# If statement being ignored when using arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to have my code read numbers from a file, and store the lines into a string array using the .split method

after this it is to check if the elements of that array are equal to certain strings, but the if statement i use for this is ignored and the following command runs anyway.

Can someone please help me and tell me why this is happening?

My code is as follows and following the code is the exact contents of the file used, too recreate if necessary name the file "inrecords.dat"

```
package project04;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Project04 
{
    static BufferedReader fin;
    static FileOutputStream fout;
    static String line = "b";
    static String line1;

    public static void fio()
    {

        String [] num = new String[1000];
        String [] num0 = new String[1];
        try
        { 
         fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inrecords.dat"));

         int cnt = 0;

        try
        {
            while(cnt <= 29)
            {
                line = fin.readLine();
                num0 = line.split("");
                int ctr = line.length();
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(num0[4]+num0[5]);
                cnt++;

                int a = 0;
                while(a <= (ctr-1))
                {
                    if(num0[a].equals("7") && num0[a+1].equals("3") && num0[a+2].equals("5"))
                        {
                            line1 = line;
                            System.out.println(line1);
                        }
                    a++;
                }

            }
        }

        catch (IOException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
        {
            System.out.println("Error 1");
        }
            try
            {
            fin.close();
            }   
            catch(IOException a)
            {
                System.out.println("Error 1a");
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException | NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error 2");
        }
       }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        fio();

    }

    }
```

Contents of file "inrecords.dat"

```
Zimmerman, Frederick A.       (301)640-7354 
Thomas, Charles G.            (301)735-1293 
Pearl, Minnie I.              (202)586-7424 
Blackwell, Constance J.       (202)931-4412 
Payne, Isaac H.               (301)426-9982 
Mitchell, Grayson T.          (301)424-6574 
Borges, Emmanuel              (301)429-3406 
Risher, Margaret V.           (202)839-6668
Mulvahill, Margaret T.        (301)735-3345 
Lum, Ewella F.                (301)664-8591 
Gray, Ronald D.               (301)884-3506 
Plummer, Bentley M.           (301)680-5928 
Bennett, Nyra B.              (301)735-7434 
Johnston, Sharon N.           (301)648-4805 
Thomas, June D.               (202)735-5400 
Ice, Ann-Marie                (301)647-9537
Jones, MaryAnn                (301)324-5343 
Harris, Melany L.             (301)836-5113 
Gunter, Stehanie              (301)942-4056 
Hill, Carolyn G.              (301)735-3891 
McCormick, Patricia W.        (301)822-5975 
Dougherty, Shannon V.         (301)252-3250 
Knight, Nicki P.              (301)408-7357 
Moore, Valerie C.             (301)345-2023 
Edwards, Muriel A.            (301)735-8649 
Jones, Jenny J.               (301)735-0659 
Bowman, Elizabeth N.          (301)735-9535 
Goodwin, Norma H.             (301)372-3443 
Harley, Albert C.             (301)364-0512
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. Step through the code and see exactly why the code is behaving contrary to your expectations.  The code is doing what you told it to do.  It's your assumptions that need correcting.

Comment: @user2204661 What do you mean by "the if statement is being ignored? Is it running when you're not expecting it to or vice versa?

Comment: I say it is being ignored because there are numbers that include 7, 3, 5

but as the code executes it does not seem to catch any of them

i have gone through the code line by line but i cannot spot a problem

thank you for your reply

Comment: Also, if you're just looking for phone numbers with "735", you can use the `contains()` or the `indexOf()` methods. See String [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: @user2204661 So you're looking for numbers that contain the sequence "735"?

Comment: Dennis,

this answered my question and saved me code! Thank you dude for your help.

Comment: @fdsa yes, exactly

Dennis has pointed out to use the contains method and that worked perfectly 

thanks to all for the help, this is a great community and i will try to contribute!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. You will have an array index of bound exception when `a >= ctr-2` for the following segment of your code:

   ```
     while(a <= (ctr-1))
     {
       if(num0[a].equals("7") && num0[a+1].equals("3") && num0[a+2].equals("5"))
        // other code                   
     }
   ```

   use a `for` loop instead: `for(a=0; a < ctr.length-3; a++)`
2. Always catch the exception and try to print stack trace or log it: Which tell you what kind of exception you might have. printing `Error 1a` or `Error 2` is not going to tell anybody what really happened.

Comment: how exactly do you log the exception, does this work like Androids logcat?

Comment: Check out the [Chained Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html) tutorial page for details. There are other advanced logger available too, but start with the one that comes built in

Comment: Cool i will do this

thanks to you for the help, this is a great community and i will try to contribute!

Comment: Make sure to check [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to know how contribution work. Please don't take it other way, i always do this to let the new user know how this site works. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Great i will check it out.